# Compare rows of a data frame and remove them under conditions

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
name school age
 jon  a      10
 jon  a      15
 jon  b      20
 jon  c      25
 jon  x      30
 jon  y      60
```

I want to compare row1 with row2 and row2 with row3 and so on. and when age1>age2 remove the row
of age 2
so the final output for this example will be like this:

```
name school age
 jon   y     60
```

this the code I wrote

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Jon", "Jon", "Jon", "Jon", "Jon")
school <- c("a", "a", "c", "b", "x", "y")
Age <- c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 60)

dfOriginal <- data.frame(Name, school, Age )

for(i in 1:nrow(dfOriginal))
{
  age1 <- dfOriginal[i, "Age"]
   #print(age1)


  for(j in 2:nrow(dfOriginal))
 { 

age2 <- dfOriginal[j, "Age"]

if(is.na(age1) | is.na(age2))
  break

if(age1 > age2)
  dfOriginal <- dfOriginal[-c(j),]

if(age2>age1)
 dfOriginal <- dfOriginal[-c(i),]

if(age1 == age2)
  dfOriginal <- dfOriginal[-c(i),]
 }
}
```

but this code gives me this result:

```
 jon c 25
 jon y 60
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to compare any of these. What you need is:

1. Arrange the values in decreasing order.
2. Choose the highest values.

```
#let's assume that your data is stored in a dataframe called df
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
df = as_data_frame(df) #convert your data to a dataframe to be sure
df <- df %>%
  arrange(desc(df)) #now you have an arranged dataframe

df <- df[1,] #I assume that your headers are not in the
```